# run python script on vagrant up

Tags: python, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to run a vagranfile that will result in a running python flask app. I've tried using this as the last command to achieve this - 
`config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "python app.py"`
But it resulted with the following error -

`*`path`for shell provisioner does not exist on the host system: /Users/*****/code/app-vagrant/python app.py`

I understand that the script is trying to run this command from the host machine, how do I make Vagrant run the script on the vagrant machine launched?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have 2 options to run a script using the [vagrant shell provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) you must pass either the `inline` or `path` argument:

> *inline* (string) - Specifies a shell command inline to execute on the remote machine.
>
> *path* (string) - Path to a shell script to upload and execute. It can be a script relative to the project Vagrantfile or a remote script (like a gist).

so when you pass `:path => "python app.py"`  the system tries to find a script named `python app.py` on your host.

replace using `inline` argument and it will achieve what you want

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "python app.py"
```

note: provisioner are run as `root` user by default, if you want to change and run it as `vagrant` user:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "python app.py", :privileged => false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start app when the machine start, you can do that:

1. move your `python app code directory` to the Vagrantfile's directory
2. Config the Vagrantfile like that:

   ```
   config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
     python /vagrant/<your python app code directory>/app.py
   SHELL
   ```